# Суммировать числа в массиве с одинаковыми значениями

Tags: php

array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [price] => 5.30
        [currency] => EUR
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 5.30
        [currency] => EUR
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [price] => 8.20
        [currency] => USD
    ) )`
```

Подскажите как сложить числа с где `[currency]` будет одинаковый ?

Comment: Добавил решение с одним проходом по массиву .... заодно почитай о встроенных функциях PHP - это полезно

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский я стараюсь применять встроенные функции, но еще маловато опыта и про все функции не знаю, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать только через 2 цикла это, в первом собираем всё в массив с ключем `currency` и значением - суммой колонок `price`.

Вторым циклом собираем массив в исходный вариант:

```
$array = [
    [
        'price' => 5.30,
        'currency' => 'EUR'
    ],
    [
        'price' => 5.30,
        'currency' => 'EUR'
    ],
    [
        'price' => 8.20,
        'currency' => 'EUR'
    ],
    [
        'price' => 5.30,
        'currency' => 'USD'
    ]
];

$data = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    //Возможно можно и без этого но кажется будет ошибка при 1 вызове
    if (array_key_exists($item['currency'], $data)) {
        $data[$item['currency']] += $item['price'];
    }
    else {
        $data[$item['currency']] = $item['price'];
    }
}

$result = [];
foreach ($data as $currency => $price) {
    array_push($result, [
        'price' => $price,
        'currency' => $currency
    ]);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Результат будет:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    'price' =>
    double(18.8)
    'currency' =>
    string(3) "EUR"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    'price' =>
    double(5.3)
    'currency' =>
    string(3) "USD"
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Как много телодвижений)

Comment: Ну вот если бы не надо было выводить в таком же виде как и входящий массив обошлось бы всё одним циклом, ну а так пришлось 2 делать, сам стараюсь обходить их всегда)

Comment: Да кому он нужен, этот  "как и входящий массив" ))

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю зачем такие гигантские конструкции у отвечающих, циклы, если в *PHP* имеются уже готовые функции для работы.

В частности достаточно воспользоваться **[array_map](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php)**, которая применяет callback-функцию ко всем элементам указанных массивов и складывает результат обхода в переменную. Получается так:

- Нет такого ключа? Тогда заносим начальную цену.
- Есть такой ключ? Тогда прибавляем к уже существующей сумме по ключу пришедшую цену.

Вот решение компактней некуда:

```
$input = $array = [
    [
        'price' => 5.30,
        'currency' => 'EUR'
    ],
    [
        'price' => 5.30,
        'currency' => 'EUR'
    ],
    [
        'price' => 8.20,
        'currency' => 'EUR'
    ],
    [
        'price' => 5.30,
        'currency' => 'USD'
    ]
];

$result = [];
array_map(function ($item) use (&$result) {
    $result[$item['currency']] = isset($result[$item['currency']]) ? $result[$item['currency']] + $item['price'] : $item['price']; 
}, $input);
```

---

Итог будет такой:

```
Array
(
    [EUR] => 18.8
    [USD] => 5.3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Простое решение - циклом foreach. Также можно использовать array_filter

```
$arr = [['price' => 5.30, 'currency' => 'EUR'], ['price' => 5.30, 'currency' => 'EUR'], ['price' => 8.20, 'currency' => 'USD']];

    $sumEUR = 0;
    $sumUSD = 0;

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        switch ($value['currency']) {
            case 'EUR':
                $sumEUR += $value['price'];
                break;

            case 'USD':
                $sumUSD += $value['price'];
                break;
        }
    }

    var_dump($sumEUR);
    var_dump($sumUSD);
```